# Showing alert panel when inventory reaches critical

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to show when an inventory is lower than critical. It doesn't seem to get there when I debug the system

This is my code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      GetInventory();
      TotalCount();
      CriticalItem();
      Panel1.Visible = false;
}

void TotalCount()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'Total Count of Inventory ' + '(' + convert(nvarchar,SUM(Quantity)) + ')' AS TotalCount from Inventory";
    SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (data.HasRows)
    {
        while (data.Read())
        {
            lblTotalCount.Text = data["TotalCount"].ToString();

        }
        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}

void GetInventory()
{


    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Inventory.InventoryID, Products.ProductName, " +
        "Supplier.SupplierName, Inventory.Quantity, Users.LastName + ', ' + Users.FirstName AS UserAccount, " +
        "SupplierProducts.CriticalLevel, Inventory.Status, Inventory.DateAdded, Inventory.DateModified, SupplierProducts.Price FROM Inventory " +
        "INNER JOIN SupplierProducts ON Inventory.ProductID = SupplierProducts.SupplierProductID " + 
        "INNER JOIN Products ON SupplierProducts.ProductID = Products.ProductID " +
        "INNER JOIN Supplier ON Inventory.SupplierID = Supplier.SupplierID " + 
        "INNER JOIN Users ON Inventory.UserID = Users.UserID";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Inventory");
    lvInventory.DataSource = ds;
    lvInventory.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

void CriticalItem()
{
    var intcheck = new DataTable();
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Inventory", con))
    {
        da.Fill(intcheck);
    }

    var critcheck = new DataTable();
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SupplierProducts", con))
    {
        da.Fill(critcheck);
    }

    int finalQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(intcheck.Rows[0]["Quantity"]);
    int criticalLevel = Convert.ToInt32(critcheck.Rows[0]["CriticalLevel"]);


    if (finalQuantity > criticalLevel)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        criticalItem.Text = "Available";
    }
}
```

I want to criticalItem.text to tell the Inventory that is less than its critical level.

Comment: You have a condition that checks if the quantity is greater than critical level. Where's the opposite check?

Comment: What do you mean _It doesn't seem to get there_? What's preventing it from doing so?  If you can debug it you must be able to see what's happening.

Comment: @mason the else is that it will not show the panel

Comment: @markpsmith I debug it and it load, but I set the inventory lower already than the critical level and it is not showing the panel

Comment: There is no else. You didn't write one. If you got this far, surely you can figure out how to write one? Else if finalQuanity is less than or equal to criticalLevel then set panel visibility to true and set the criticalItem text to "warning, critical!"

Comment: @mason  it did show, but I want to show the inventory that is critical